# Как лучше проверить наличие записей в БД с большим списком в условии?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Допустим есть 1 млн юзеров (id из вк, допустим) и есть список из 10 000 id (из них только штук 1-100 есть в БД).
Как само быстро и правильно будет получить имеющихся юзеров в базе?

Слишком хардово сделать так?

```
mysqli_query($db,"select id from users
where id in(232344,432903,340003,439044,7468976 ... и таких 10000)")
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше.

Comment: Можно поместить эти 10000 ID в отдельную (временную) таблицу, после чего воспользоваться `JOIN` или подзапросом в `IN()`.

Comment: кстати про `JOIN` против `IN(подзапрос)`: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/03/25/mysql-in-query-performance/

Answer (score 1):

Первый вопрос, которым стоит задаться, - это почему искомые 10,000 ID не находятся в БД, в которой выполняется запрос. Откуда они берутся?

Более элегантным решением было бы иметь список значений к проверке в отдельной таблице в той же базе (в крайнем случае, загрузить их во временную таблицу), и использовать `JOIN`. [Тут](http://explainextended.com/2009/08/18/passing-parameters-in-mysql-in-list-vs-temporary-table/) товарищ замерял и у него вышло, что это быстрее для больших списков, но лучше, конечно, замерять самостоятельно.

Нужно также иметь в виду, что на длину запроса обычно накладываются ограничения (в MySQL см. [`max_allowed_packet`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html)).

Формировать текст запроса строковыми операциями вообще не очень элегантно по различным причинам: от увеличивающейся вероятности синтаксических ошибок и SQL injection до накладных на разбор однотипных SQL-запросов, отличающихся лишь параметрами. Поэтому, я бы взял за правило избегать динамической генерации SQL операциями со строками.